# put_session update not persisting data over page change

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In an Elixir Phoenix project, I try to keep track of open editing pages to prevent that two open tabs interfere with each other by manipulating the session variable of the Plug.Conn.

Putting

```
conn = 
    conn |> put_session(:open_articles, [])
```

in the landing page of the project, every time an editing page is opened through the controller, I update the session by

```
conn = 
    conn|> put_session(:open_articles, [new_article | get_session(conn, :open_articles)])
```

While the new article is appended to the list while on the page, it drops it immediately after changing the page. What is it that I am getting wrong ?

Comment: How are you reading back the session? Also, you're using the `|` backwards: `[prepended_item | existing_items]`

Comment: I read it back again with get_session, but I also IO.inspected the conn and the conn.private.plug_session did not have the articles added on the previous page.